# tansfer data using bluetooth in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-broadcast

can anyone please guide me in achieving following functionality in my app, I am new in Android development and want to try hands on bluetooth.

I have an application that creates business or personal cards (having all the information)
and store them in database as Json string.

Now, I want to send this card (the corresponding JSON string) to other user (who also has my application via bluetooth).

Now, I know how to do about simple things like , turning on-off bluetooth, discovering devices and showing it to the user (from where user can select the device he wants to send the card)

Now, how should I do the rest of the things?
that is:

1)Actually send the json string?
     Can anyone suggest a good tutorial where actually some sort of data is transfered via 
     Bluetooth.

2)Now, when the data gets transferred to the user's phone, it should be handled by my application. That is the string that will be received should be stored in the application's database. But, how would my application know that the data received via bluetooth concerns with the application. (I mean, any sort of data of any other application can be transferred via bluetooth , but how would my application know that the string (a Card) from my application has been received). I think it has to do something with bradCast intent or BroadCAst receiver?

But how should I implement this?

What if the application on the receiving side is not running and a card is sent to it?
How should my application react and store the card in application's database?

3) what is UUID? Do I require it for my application.

Thankyou!!

Answer (score 0):

1. If u are trying to communicate between two android device then Sample BluetoothChat code is best to understand the basic communication  ...Helpul links:::[**link1**](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html)  [**link2**](http://manojprasaddevelopers.blogspot.in/2012/02/bluetooth-data-transfer-example.html)
2. to distinguish data sent::
   in ur app u can use an header for ur msg and on the other end on receiving data check header whether tat msg is concerned with ur application

example:: on receiving msg check header as below

```
public static boolean isValidHeader(EnhancedByteBuffer paramEnhancedByteBuffer)
{
 boolean bool = false;
  while (true)
  {

  paramEnhancedByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
  int i = paramEnhancedByteBuffer.position();
  long l = paramEnhancedByteBuffer.getUint32();
  int k = paramEnhancedByteBuffer.getUint16();
  paramEnhancedByteBuffer.position(i);
  if ((l == userdefined1) && (k =userdefined2 )
    bool = true;
       return bool;
  }
 }
```

here  `userdefined1` and `userdefined2` can be some value which u use to differentiate ur msg, 
if it returns `true` its understood tat its ur application msg else not..

3.UUID is an immutable representation of a 128-bit universally unique identifier (UUID). and yes u do require it for your application [Extra details on UUID](http://www.enough.de/javadoc/j2me/de/enough/polish/android/bluetooth/UUID.html)

Comment: remove boolean bool = false and the bool = true line.  then just return true/false